# Need an explanation on how code from journal works

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I was reading a paper from [Mathematica Journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/AlgebraicProgramming/AlgebraicProgramming.pdf). It gives code for calculating subsets.

```
subSets[s_List] := Variables /@ (Expand[Times @@ (1 + s)] /. Plus -> List) // Sort
```

Then it says that the following code is an optimized version.

```
subSetsV[s_List] :=  Distribute[{{}, {#}} & /@ s, List, List, List, Union] // Sort
```

My problem is that I can not understand the code. Can someone please help me with bit of explanation.

Comment: For the first one, why don't you assign `s` a concrete instance of a list (say `{a,b,c}` - assuming `a`, `b`, `c` haven't been assigned values) and work through the expression inside out? Start with `(1+{a,b,c})`, then `Times@@(1+{a,b,c})` and so on and so forth.

Comment: The second one is clever, but to find the details of that form of `Distribute` you'll need to look in the details section of the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Distribute.html).

Comment: Of course, if the entries of the input list are numeric, then the first snippet won't work. I'd have done `Sort[Variables[List @@ Expand[Times @@ (1 + s)]]]`, tho.

Comment: For example, in second what does continuous List means? This example is as it is in doc as well.

Comment: To help you learn how to catch fish, execute these in sequence: `s = {1, 2, 3};`, `{{}, {#}} & /@ s`, `Distribute[{{}, {#}} & /@ s, List]` (same as `Distribute[{{}, {#}} & /@ s, List, List]`, why?), and then finally `Distribute[{{}, {#}} & /@ s, List, List, g, f]`. You should be able to see a few patterns.